# How to retrieve related list label changes from translation workbench

Tags: translation, translation-workbench

I have renamed the related List label by following the below steps

```
Setup --> Translation Workbench --> Override. 

Select the filter criteria: 

Package {!Name of the Installed Package}
Language     "English"
Setup Component  "Custom Field"
Object   {!Name of the Object}
Aspect   "Related List Label"
```

Now i want to retrieve this from pacakge.xml . But not able to get the related List Label.
Can any one please help me to retrieve the changes for renaming the related list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Translation Workbench CustomObjectTranslation Metadata](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/172187/translation-workbench-customobjecttranslation-metadata)

Comment: @DavidCheng No. The mentioned link specifies how to translate the custom field and object name . I need the meta.xml for relabeling the related List Label

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomFieldTranslation xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <label>FieldLabel</label>
    <name>FieldApiName</name>
    <relationshipLabel>(RelatedListLabel which you want to rename</relationshipLabel>
</CustomFieldTranslation>
```